# Text Rank Algorithm to find Keywords

Tags: text-mining

I was trying to implement the text rank algorithm mentioned in :
http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/acl2004/emnlp/pdf/Mihalcea.pdf

It seems to be simple to implement in python but I could not get the exact result as the authors have got in the paper for the example text that they mentioned.
Just wondering if anyone has tried their hands on this ?
Any general opinion on this algorithm ? Any recommendations to tune it further ?